# Removing Visual Editor On a Specific Page

Tags: wordpress

I been trying to remove Visual Editor from a specific page only. I managed to remove Visual editor from *all* pages using this code

```
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit', 'patrick_user_can_richedit');

function patrick_user_can_richedit($c) {
global $post_type;

if ('page' == $post_type)
return false;
return $c;
}
```

Is there any way I can remove the visual editor from only one page? Im using Wordpress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geez ... how many forums are you gonna post this question on?  lol ... That was the same solution I posted on the .org forums ... but ...

I told you the better solution was to not tinker with the core WP files, and just use a plugin like this: [Disable WYSIWYG on Specific Pages or Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-visual-editor-wysiwyg/)

This way, you're not tinkering with the core WP files, and when you update your WP, you won't lose all your changes ... so you don't have to keep a personal changelog handy.

Remember the rule:  "When in doubt, don't" ... if you're thinking of changing all your php files, and you're unsure as to whether you should or not, don't.

Comment: A junior dev used this solution for a field that needed to be plain text for html email templates and it caused a lot of problems as it still shows the visual editor if you enter the page after using the visual editor on another page - it just hides the tab to switch to the visual editor. Switching to the text editor after that preserves all the reformatting the visual editor does so you end up with malformed html.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
// removes rich text editor for certain pages
function remove_pages_editor(){
    if(get_the_ID() === 95) {
        remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
    } // end if
} // end remove_pages_editor
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'remove_pages_editor' );
```

Comment: This removes the content editor altogether... both visual and text tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some Plugin to add custom field (Advanced Custom Fields is the best), then use it in the following code:

```
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit', 'on_post_user_can_richedit');
function on_post_user_can_richedit($c) {
    global $post_type;
    $sw_off_visual_editor = get_field('sw_off_visual_editor');

    if(!empty($sw_off_visual_editor) && $sw_off_visual_editor[0] == 1)
        return false;
    return $c;
}
```

I added custom checkbox, take it from get_field('sw_off_visual_editor');, then test it $sw_off_visual_editor[0] == 1.

Answer (score 0):

To REMOVE only the [Visual] Tab, and force HTML/TEXT, this will work. You can add other page_id to the if command to target other pages.

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer', 'removes_editor_visual_tab', 99 );

function removes_editor_visual_tab()
{
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    if($post_id == 1434){
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        a#content-tmce, a#content-tmce:hover {
            display:none;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                document.getElementById("content-tmce").onclick = 'none';
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```